# meta-policy (strict policy files) question

Tags: apache-flex

I am having problems accessing 3rd party web services from my Flex app, and a couple of other posts are helping me with other issues, but I am getting a warning:

Warning: Domain MYDOMAINHERE does not specify a meta-policy.  Applying default meta-policy 'master-only'.  This configuration is deprecated.  See

http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files to fix this problem.

Do I need to fix this problem now, or should it work with the default meta-policy and I need to address this at some point?

Thanks very much for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remvove the warning, add this line in your crossdomain.xml :

```
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
```

However I recommand you to read [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_0) article first, because several meta-policies are available, and maybe you will choose something else thant the default "master-only" value.